# Q&A - scalastyle - illegal start of simple expression: Token(RPAREN,),135,))

Tags: scalastyle

The original codes:

```
  def args: List[String] = List(
    "parameter1",
  )
```

When run scalastyle, the error message is:

```
illegal start of simple expression: Token(RPAREN,),135,))
```

The error message didn't show any information.

Answer (score -1):

It's because of extra comma. So the correct way is:

```
  def args: List[String] = List(
    "parameter1"
  )
```

Comment: There is no point answering questions that aren't reproducible or contain a typo. Comment and/or close vote such

Comment: I add this Q and A for further reference. Because there is no explicit reason why it raises error. It is from my end and I fixed it by removing comma. At least it offers one option to fix the error.

Comment: Such questions are off-topic on SO. There is a reason there is a vote-close option for these

Answer (score -1):

Error is because of an extra comma

corrected code :
def args: List[String] = List(
"parameter1"
)

Comment: There is no point answering questions that aren't reproducible or contain a typo. Comment and/or close vote such